# Find local extrema in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, persistence

I am trying to find local extrema in a [root](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) histogram. My idea is to the bin contents in an array and use [pesistence1d class](http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~weinkauf/notes/persistence1d.html).

The first step is to create a simple `float` array and use the class, with the following simple code

```
#include "persistence1d.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace p1d;

int main()
{
    float y[3] = {2,1,2}; 
    //cout << y[0] << y[1] << y[2] << endl; 

    //Run persistence on data - this is the main call.
    Persistence1D p;
    p.RunPersistence(y);

    return 0;

}
```

The thing is that when I compile this code using `g++ extrema.cpp` I get the following error

```
extrema.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
extrema.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘p1d::Persistence1D::RunPersistence(float [3])’ 
persistence1d.hpp:128: note: candidates are: bool p1d::Persistence1D::RunPersistence(const std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&)
```

I cannot understand why this error occurs! Any idea or advice would be more than welcome!

Comment: The error seems quite clear to me. You are trying to pass an array to a function that doesn't expect an array as a parameter. What is your confusion?

Comment: I thought that `vectors` and `arrays` are the same thing...

Comment: You thought wrong, I'm afraid. Array is a block of memory that contains a number of objects. `std::vector` is a class (which happens contain to a dynamically allocated array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing a vector instead of an array:

```
std::vector<float> y;
y.push_back(2); y.push_back(1); y.push_back(2);
Persistence1D p;
p.RunPersistence(y);
```